# Gridlayout разделитель строк

Tags: java, android

Можно ли как то линиями разделить строчки в `GridLayout`

```
        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:rowCount="6"
            android:columnCount="22">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/id"
                android:id="@+id/textViewID"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_row="0" />


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textID"
                android:layout_row="0"
                android:layout_column="21"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />



            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/district"
                android:id="@+id/textViewDistrict"
                android:layout_row="1"
                android:layout_column="0" />
```

Первые два `TextView`находятся на одной линии, третий `TextView` находиться уже на второй линии

Comment: покажите, как хотите разделить, можно разными путями. выложите вашу разметку тогда и ответ будет точней.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно когда говорят Grid, ожидаю увидеть +100500 кастомных View раскиданных по углам. Попробуйте так:

### Ваш GridLayout

```
<GridLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:rowCount="6"
android:columnCount="22"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:background="@drawable/frame"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ТЕКСТ_1"
    android:id="@+id/textViewID"
    android:layout_column="0"
    android:layout_row="0" />

<TextView
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/frame"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textID"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:text="ТЕКСТ_2"
    android:layout_column="21"
    android:layout_gravity="right" />

<TextView
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:background="@drawable/frame"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ТЕКСТ_3"
    android:id="@+id/textViewDistrict"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="0" />
</GridLayout>
```

### frame.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<stroke android:color="#c1000000"
    android:width="2dp"/>
<corners android:radius="1dp"/>
<solid android:color="#36000000"/>
</shape>
```

Есть вариант еще сделать подкладку с цветом и установить отступы между view, но этот вариант более гибкий.